# How to use .h.gch files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, header-files, precompiled-headers

I recently found out about precompiled headers in `C++`, specifically for `gcc` compilers.
I did find something about the `.h.gch` files on the net, but haven't yet been able to use them.

I need to know:

1. How to create a `.h.gch` file?
   My code isn't creating one?
2. Once created, how to use it?
   do you include it like any other user-defined file? 
   ex: `#include "SomeCode.h.gch"`

Or is there some other way of using it?
please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using GCH (Gnu preCompiled Headers) is easy, at least in theory.

#### How to create a GCH

Just use `gcc <compiler-options> myfile.h`. That will create `myfile.h.gch`. You can use the `-o <name>` to specify the name of the output file.

If your header file is C++, you will have to name it `myfile.hpp` or `myfile.hh`, or GCC will try to compile it as C and probably fail. Alternatively you can use the `-x c++-header` compiler option.

#### How to use a GCH

Put your `myfile.h.gch` in the same directory than `myfile.h`. Then it will be used automatically instead of `myfile.h`, at least as long as the compiler options are the same.

If you do not want to (or can) to put your `*.gch` in the same directory of your `*.h`, you can move them to a directory, say `./gch`, and add the option `-Igch` to your compiler command.

#### How to know your GCH is being used

Use `gcc -H <compiler-options> myfile.c`. That will list the included files. If your `myfile.h.gch` does not appear, or has an `x`, then something is wrong. If it appears with a `!`, congratulations! You are using it.

Comment: i tried the `gcc -H` option but instead of `gcc`, I used `g++` and an infinite loop of some sort began
anyways, i did get my `.h.gch` file, just dont yet know if it is being used

Comment: The only result in google about "-Igch" is your comment. Where did you get this from?

Comment: @MaciejZałucki: You are reading it as an option called `Igck`, but it is actually an option `I` plus an argument `gch`: `-I` is the well-known switch to add a directory to the header search list; and `gch` is just the name of the directory I made up `./gch`.

Comment: The way you wrote it is a bit misleading then :) I figured it out, GCC looks for precompiled headers the same way it is looking for headers - first match from include directories is used. One thing I have to check is if it is first looking for .h.gch everywhere and then for .h, or it is looking for .h.gch then .h in each include dir. I suspect it's latter so the ```-I /gch/dir``` needs to be included before the header itself.